# LINQ: Join two tables and group by all records (Matched + Unmatched)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have two independent tables, "Task" and "Report" with a common column "CustomerId".

I wish to group by these two tables by CustomerId  and combine their results into a new list.

If some task or report does not have a matching customerId, then that task/report should have an independent group with their own customerId as key and count 1 as shown below in the required result.

How can I achieve this in LINQ and efcore?

**Table1: Task**

| TaskId | Description | CustomerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Task1 | 1 |
| 2 | Task2 | 1 |
| 3 | Task3 | 2 |
| 4 | Task4 | 7 |

**Table2: Report**

| ReportId | Summary | CustomerId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Report1 | 1 |
| 2 | Report2 | 2 |
| 3 | Report3 | 3 |

Want to get this result ⬇️

**Required Result**

**Group 1:   CustomerId: 1   Count(3)**

TaskId 1

TaskId 2

ReportId 1

--------------------------------------

**Group 2:   CustomerId: 2   Count(2)**

TaskId 3

ReportId 2

------------------------------------------

**Group 3:   CustomerId: 3   Count(1)**

ReportId 3

------------------------------------------

**Group 4:   CustomerId: 7   Count(1)**

TaskId 4

I can join two tables and group by them but then only get matched records, I want to get all records, I have not come across a solution as yet and I would truly appreciate any help.
--Update--

```cs
public class GroupedItems<T> where T : class
{
    public string GroupName { set; get; }
    public int GroupCount { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<T> Items { set; get; }
}
```

I wish to get

```cs
GroupedItems<ReportTaskDTO>
```

where if group name is **CustomerId 1** then Items should have two task and one report and group count should be 3.

Comment: [LEFT JOIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#left-join) + [GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7325306/10646316). Anyway, show your model and what you have tried.

Comment: Show your code. Query is simple and we do not understand complexity.

Comment: @Svyatoslav If you look more carefully, the query is not simple (and not even doable) in EFC. Client side, yes. Server side - no way currently (out of the box).

Comment: @MaryamAfzal, update question with result class. From fiddle it is not clear.

Comment: I deleted the fiddle as it was not clear. I do need it in entity framework AsQuerable. @SvyatoslavDanyliv. I will update the question with result class.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Thank you for your answer, I updated the question, I simplified the models but in real I have a lot of extra fields. And for ReportTaskDto I am not sure how I should set it. I need suggestions for that, so that I could get report and task as a separate item in List of Items. for example for group3 there will be only one report item and null task.

Comment: `IEnumerable<T> Items` tells me that you have to group items on the client side. Add to the question `Task` and `Report` model.

Comment: No, I have to group on server side, as an example **` await combinedQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.CustomerId)
                    .GroupBy(d => d.CustomerId, i => i,
                        (key, v) => new GroupedItems<ReportTaskDto>
                        {
                            GroupName = key.ToString(),
                            GroupCount = v.Count(),
                            Items = v.Select(x =>
                                new ReportTaskDto
                                {

                                })
                        });`**